# Compare each column cell value to the next column cell value in a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

If I have a DataGridView and I need to compare the values of cells with another cells how to do it?

Detail:
I need to compare the value of each cell with the value in the left neighboring cell.

Below is the function and the logic of what I want to do:

```
protected void gdData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Loop IS REQUIRED NEED HELP ON HOW TO STRUCTURE IT TO Compare 
    //values of 1st cell to the next cell
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[2] < e.Row.Cells[3])
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
        else
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#008000");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the values from the source data, not the cells. Note that `gv.Columns.Count` will only work on TemplateField and BoundField, not autogenerated colums.

```
//check if the row is d datarow
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //cast the row back to a datarowview
    DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

    //cast the sender back to the gridview
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;

    //loop all the columns
    for (int i = 1; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        //compare
        if ((int)row[i] > (int)row[i -1])
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i - 1].ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```